# FolderBrowseDialog() with user specified location

Tags: vb.net, folderbrowserdialog

Using VS2013 with VB.NET and using the FileBrowseDialog(), I can't seem to see the property to have it use either the last location selected OR be able to specify a directory to start in based on the contents of a text box.

The code works great for opening and posting the `.SelectedPath` where I need it but now I want it to start in a specific location.

Tried .ROOT but that doesn't seem to allow me to specify a starting position other then an enumerated value.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to set the SelectedPath before trying to open the FolderBrowserDialog?

```
Dim fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog()
fbd.SelectedPath = "your path variable"
if fbd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then

   string newPath = fbd.SelectedPath
   .....
```

[From MSDN FolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.selectedpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> If the SelectedPath property is set before showing the dialog box, the
>   folder with this path will be the selected folder, as long as
>   SelectedPath is set to an absolute path that is a subfolder of
>   RootFolder (or more accurately, points to a subfolder of the shell
>   namespace represented by RootFolder).